# Azure cli to filter Instances using tags

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-vm, azure-cli2

I am trying to filter instances based on tags, but it is giving me all the instances present in the resource group. I need to list Instances which has a specific tag. I am using the below command to list instances that have `wknhscale == 'active'` tag, is there an issue with the command? Also is there any other efficient to achieve this?

`az vm list --query '[?tags.wknhscale == 'active'].{Name:name, RG:resourceGroup}' -o table`

I am looking for a simple query to fetch Instances with tags, like in gcp

`gcloud compute instances list --project test --filter='labels.wknhscale:active AND name ~ .*wkn*' --sort-by=creationTimestamp --format='value(name,zone)'`

Comment: I would strongly suggest writing a script which a) calls your "az vm list" query, then b) further processes the returned text.  In fact, you might just want to do the whole thing in Powershell, which is both a "full featured scripting language" *AND* an Azure API.  But I'm not sure how far you can go just by adding parameters to your CLI query...

Comment: Are you running into any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to query using az graph query.  Thanks, @azMantas

```
az graph query -q "Resources |  where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' | where tags['wknhscale']=='active' |  where name startswith 'workernode' | project name | order by name asc" | jq '.data[].name'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Azure Resource Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview) for this. Resource graph allows you to query all your Azure resources (in all subscriptions that you have access to) using the Kusto language either in the CLI or in the portal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can't I achieve the same from `az vm list` query

Comment: Thanks for the Hint, I was able to retrieve using azure graph query